# Show that $K [\Bbb Z]$ is an integral domain.

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain, group-rings

> Let $K$ be a field. Then show that the group ring $K [\Bbb Z]$ is an integral domain.

How do I show that $K[\Bbb Z]$ contains no divisor of zero? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $K[\Bbb{Z}]\cong K[X,X^{-1}]$ is a subring of the field $K(X)$ (of rational functions in $X$)

Comment: @reuns $K[X,X^{-1}] = K[X]_{X}.$ Since $K[X]$ is an integral domain and the underlying multiplicatively closed set doesn't contain $0$ in it (It contains the identity of the integral domain and all the positive integer powers of $X$) it follows that $K[X]_{X}$ is an integral domain and hence $K[X,X^{-1}]$ is an integral domain and therefore according to your remark it turns out that $K[\Bbb Z]$ is also an integral domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $K[\mathbb{Z}]$ is isomorphic (as $K$-algebra) to the Laurent polynomial ring $K[X,X^{-1}]$ (identify $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $X^n$), which is an integral domain, being the localization of $K[X]$, an integral domain, in the multiplicative set consisting of the non-negative powers of X.

This is actually an elementary instance of the complicated Kaplansky's conjecture, stated more in general when $\mathbb{Z}$ is replaced by a torsion-free group $G$. You can look at https://mathoverflow.net/q/79559/158845 to have an idea about the state of art and the techniques implied.

EDIT: to avoid the use of localization, one can just observe, as precisely pointed out by @reuns in a comment, that $K[X,X^{-1}]$ is a subring of $K(X)$, the field of rational functions in $X$ over $K$. $K(X)$ is just the field of fractions of the integral domain $K[X]$ (have you heard about "field of fractions"? I can go more in detail about this easy construction).

Comment: Even though nothing in this answer is wrong, and it adds some nice context to the question, it misses the mark a bit in its current state, I think. In particular, the case when $G = \mathbb{Z}$ is completely elementary, unlike the general case, because in this case, $K[G]$ is isomorphic to the Laurent polynomial ring $K[X, X^{-1}]$, which clearly has no zero divisors because it is a localization of an integral domain.

Comment: You’re absolutely right. I can delete or edit my answer if you think can be better.

Comment: I think your answer would be great if you edited in this information! I'd definitely give it a +1. :)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @AlexWertheim!

Comment: I am sorry to say that I am unaware of what is called a *localization.* Can it be proved in a more elementary way? I have heard that Kaplansky's conjecture is easy to prove for torsion-free abelian groups. Then can't the similar way be applied to $\Bbb Z\ $?

Comment: Actually this is a direct consequence of the fact that *Localization of an integral domain is also an integral domain.*

Comment: That is exactly what is written in the first part of my answer!

Comment: But you should mention that here the underlying multiplicatively closed set $S$ doesn't contain $0$ in it. Right? For otherwise $K[X]_{X} = (0).$

Comment: Although you have mentioned it that in this case $S = \{1,X,X^2, \cdots \}.$